# Comparing if one string is substring of the other 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

So far, I have this code

```
org 100h

store MACRO str
    LOCAL skip_data, endloop, repeat, localdata

    jmp skip_data           ; Jump over data
    localdata db str, '$', 0  ; Store the macro-argument with terminators
    skip_data:
    mov si, OFFSET localdata
    mov di, OFFSET msg
    repeat:                 ; Loop to store the string
    cmp byte ptr [si], 0    ; End of string?
    je endloop              ; Yes: end of loop
    movsb                   ; No:  Copy one byte from DS:SI to ES:DI, inc SI & DI
    jmp repeat              ; Once more
    endloop:
ENDM  

store2 MACRO str
    LOCAL skip_data, endloop, repeat, localdata

    jmp skip_data           ; Jump over data
    localdata db str, '$', 0  ; Store the macro-argument with terminators
    skip_data:
    mov si, OFFSET localdata
    mov di, OFFSET msg
    repeat:                 ; Loop to store the string
    cmp byte ptr [si], 0    ; End of string?
    je endloop              ; Yes: end of loop
    movsb                   ; No:  Copy one byte from DS:SI to ES:DI, inc SI & DI
    jmp repeat              ; Once more
    endloop:
ENDM 

crlf MACRO
    LOCAL skip_data, localdata

    jmp skip_data
    localdata db 13, 10, '$'
    skip_data:
    mov dx, offset localdata
    mov ah, 09h 
    int 21h
ENDM    

ORG 100h

mov dx, OFFSET msg
mov ah, 09h 
int 21h

crlf
store "Hello!"

mov dx, OFFSET msg
mov ah, 09h 
int 21h

crlf
store "Good Bye."

mov dx, OFFSET msg
mov ah, 09h 
int 21h

;mov ax, 4C00h
;int 21h

msg db "Hello, World!", '$'  
msg2 db "Watafak", '$'          

mov dx, OFFSET msg
MOV AH, 09H
INT 21H           

crlf

msg cmp msg2
je exit
ret
```

But it isn't comparing. How do I compare if msg is a substring of msg2?

Comment: I don't see where you're even *trying* to compare the two.  Unless you mean that `msg cmp msg2` at the end, which makes absolutely no sense, and doesn't look like it'd ever even run.

Comment: We need to implement an algorith where if you enter at least three characters, all the strings that contain that must be shown..

Comment: OK, well, this code comes nowhere close to doing any of that.  Literally the only thing it's doing (besides possibly saying "hello" a lot) is copying strings around needlessly and dangerously.

Comment: so what can you suggest about it?

Comment: That you learn C.  :P  Seriously.  Look at how C does strings.  It's basically the same as you'd do in assembly language, but without the 8086's stupidity getting in the way.  Take that, and translate it to asm.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to find a better example than [**The Art of Assembly-15.3.2 Index**](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/CH15/CH15-4.html#HEADING4-153)

Sorry for the initial confusion `:)`

Comment: This has nothing to do with searching for substrings.  It'd only check whether two strings match exactly.  You probably should have copied 15.3.2 instead.  :P